# Regex to extract name from a string excluding titles + factoring multiple names

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract the name along with some other data items from around 700 PDF files all with equal formatting (but different data of course). I used PDFPig to extract the text from the PDF and am then using regex to extract the specific items in the text. I have run into a snag with my regex where i haven't accounted for (a) multiple names and (b) Titles such as Mr, Mrs, Miss etc. that are all present in front of the names. This means that currently the first name can be extracted as 'Miss' rather than the correct name.

My current Regex:
`"\b[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]{3,}\s[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]{3,}\b"`

Context in the code:

```
private void name_extraction()
{
    string namePattern = @"\b([A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]+)\s+(?:[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]+\s*)*([A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]+)\b";    /*@"\b[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]{3,}\s[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]{3,}\b";*/
    ;
    ;
    Regex nameRegex = new Regex(namePattern);
    Match nameMatch = nameRegex.Match(parsed_text.ToString());

    if (nameMatch.Success)
    {
        string extractedName = nameMatch.Value;
        int spaceIndex = extractedName.IndexOf(' ');
        string firstName = extractedName.Substring(0, spaceIndex);
        string lastName = extractedName.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
        extracted_data["FirstName"] = firstName;
        extracted_data["LastName"] = lastName;
        account_year_extraction();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name was not extracted!" + "\n" + "Check formatting of input file.");
    }
```

Input text:

> Confidential - name is the first piece of text, followed by account type and date.

Desired Output:

> FirstName: Jennifer
> LastName: Helen King

Actual output:

> FirstName: Ms
> LastName: Jennifer Helen King Re Mrs

I'm very inexperienced with regex and am stuck on the best way to approach this. Is there a way to do this with regex or will i have to extract it and then sort it afterwards? I would like the regex to extract the first name and last name without the titles and factoring in for double barrelled surnames.

Comment: In C# regex, `[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züßäö]+` can be replaced with `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+`. BUT  if the `Mr`/`Miss` etc. are always there in your Group 1, why not just get what is in Group 2? `nameMatch.Groups[2].Value`?

Comment: Does this do exactly the same thing?

Comment: I mean, if all you need is to get Group 2 value, why not use `nameMatch.Groups[2].Value`?

Comment: I have used groups later on to extract other data item. The thing I'm struggling with is the variation in names, some have 3 names some have 2, different titles interact with the Regex differently. Mr is fine and gets ignored but Miss gets picked up as a first name.

Comment: Your example for Input Text isn't really helpful. If its a free text thing you want to parse you are almost out of luck. You might get rid of salutations/titles etc. but you really can't distinguish in multi part names how many of the parts are belonging to firstname or lastname or even is a middlename or comes from a culture where ordering of those names is different. A Regex can't solve this an AI maybe.

Comment: Yeah apologies for the lack of Input text but I don't feel comfortable putting that information on here. So what your saying is that there is no way to factor in for multiple names?

Comment: This is hard, and can only be done as "good enough". Say, there are a specific amount of forms of address, and you assume that the lastname should only include capitalized words after the name that do not equal specific words, like `Re` (looks like it is your stopword). Then, something like `\b(?:Mrs?|M(?:is)?s|Dr\.?)\s+(\p{L}\p{Ll}*)((?:\s+(?!(?:Mrs?|M(?:is)?s|Dr|Re)\b)\p{L}\p{Ll}*(?:[’'-]\w+)*)+)\b` [can work](https://regex101.com/r/WwizU8/1). Group 1 will contain the first name and Group 2 (use `.Trim()` on it) will contain the last name.

Comment: Not if you don't have some knowledge about the way the files where created. If you know that for example the format will always be "Salutation Firstname Lastname" and only Salutation is optional then you might do some sort of best effort applying to first or lastname that still will be wrong sometimes . So get the count of parts and then decide how many then are firstname or lastname and accept the inevitable errors.

Comment: "but I don't feel comfortable putting that information on here" What could be problematic that we can't deduce already from the expected output you show? Just make multiple examples with random data that shows the different possible inputs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! That Regex pattern ignores the title and extracts the name, I will have to slightly adjust for the few names that are longer than 3 but should be all good from here.

Comment: @Ralf Just about anything could be problematic. You're telling me that cause I shared a name I might as well share everything else. Cheers anyway but problem solved.

Comment: [This is very relevant](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/). Also, `Old McDonald` and [`D'Arcy Carden`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Arcy_Carden) will be very upset with Wiktor's regex :)

Comment: @NPras Oh I've already ran into problems. Someones name is spelled 'Jo-Anna' rather than 'Joanna' because when they were born their parents spelled it wrong when they registered the name. This mean that the name doesn't get extracted, but the regex will do. It recognises most western names and doesn't have to be perfect for what i am doing.